# How do I get the number of a certain of event for each user?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of events that stores the events for users and I want to get the number of a specific event for each user.

An example table is called "events" and it has 2 columns

```
user_id VARCHAR(50)
event_name VARCHAR(50)
```

The user_ids are all unique and the event names can be things like login, sent_message, liked_post

How do I, for example, query for the total messages sent per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `GROUP BY` with a `COUNT`:

```
Select  user_id, 
        event_name,
        Count(*) as total
From    events
Where   event_name = 'sent_messages'
Group By user_id, event_name
```

You can remove the `WHERE` clause to get the totals for all events per user.

Comment: @user2525752 And please mark answers that gave you the correct answer as correct (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

Select User_ID, Count(Event_name) From Events
Group By User_ID